# Crosswalk - Build and Manifest

Tags: android, crosswalk-runtime

I'm using Crosswalk for projects that need to run on Android 2.2 and up.
I'm looking for any documentation about manifest.json because I didn't find anything that lists properties I can use.

I would like to know too if there is a way to manually edit AndroidManifest.xml before build in order to change permissions or SDK version.
Eventually, I would be glad if I could move the build folder from the Crosswalk-environment to my project folder. For the moment, I can only move APKs with --target-dir.
 Here is my folder structure :

```
 -MyApp_project  
     -MyApp_www
     -[Move build folder here]
 -Crosswalk-env
     -...content...
     -[build folders are there]
```

Thanks

Comment: For the documentation of manifest.json, https://github.com/crosswalk-project/crosswalk-website/wiki/Crosswalk-manifest this may help.

Comment: Thank you for this resource, this is what I was looking for ! I expected to find it on the documentation of the main site, but github is better !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm new to crosswalk, so my answer should not be perfect.

As my previous comment, the documentation of manifest.json is found in https://github.com/crosswalk-project/crosswalk-website/wiki/Crosswalk-manifest.

It says you can set `permissions` properties so you don't have to edit AndroidManifest.xml directly. (though I have not tested it)

I don't know how to handle crosswalk's SDK directory neither, 
but simple `build.bat` script like this mitigate my pain.

```
@set XWALK_HOME=c:/path/to/crosswalk-5.34.104.5
@set ARCH=x86
@set OUT=%~dp0%out

@mkdir %OUT%

@cd %XWALK_HOME%
python make_apk.py ^
 --manifest=%~dp0/src/manifest.json ^
 --package=this.is.required.for.shared.mode ^
 --target-dir=%OUT% ^
 --mode=shared ^
 --enable-remote-debug
@cd %~dp0
```

Comment: It helps me a bit and seems to work. I added some commands to move the build folder in crosswalk-5.34.104.5 to where I want. Do I need to move or copy other folders in order to build manually from the command line ? And then which command should I use : ant or aapt ?  
And sorry, I can't upvote your answer yet, I'm still new !

Comment: Once you create a script like `build.bat`, you only have to execute build.bat to building apk. No ant, no aapt and no need to move directory.

Answer (score 0):

Crosswalk doesn't support Android 2.2. It only supports Android 4.0 or later device.

Answer (score 0):

The main site is https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/manifest.html
You can also try the forthcoming packaging tool for creating Crosswalk application: https://github.com/crosswalk-project/crosswalk-app-tools